# Is there a way I can check type of database in the property/method of sqlalchemy model?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

My sqlalchemy table model has a hybrid property of the form:

```
@hybrid_property
def age_in_seconds(self) -> float:
    return (datetime.utcnow() - self.generated_at).total_seconds()

@age_in_seconds.expression
def age_in_seconds(cls):
    return func.extract("epoch", datetime.utcnow() - cls.generated_at)
```

which works fine on my production PostgreSQL database. However, the unit tests use a smaller and lighter SQLite database, which doesn't support this extract('epoch', ...) function. Is there some function db_type(...) that can give me db type based on current state of the code (so I don't have to send this to the property as an argument read from .env) that will have info about db type such that my code can become:

```
@age_in_seconds.expression
def age_in_seconds(cls):
    if db_type(...) == 'postgresql':
         return func.extract("epoch", datetime.utcnow() - cls.generated_at)
    if db_type(...) == 'sqlite':
          return func.unixepoch(datetime.utcnow()) - func.unixepoch(cls.generated_at)
```